# what is the function of list with ... in parenthesis list (...) in r

Tags: r, list

I see a chuck of code like this. It is for generating the output. What is list(...) for? Is it like the function of placeholder %s? THX

`c(list(data = data, output = list(height = height)), list(...))`

Comment: I also see **...** in user-written functions, like ```iteratecounts = function(variables, outcomes, output, ... , Nmax = 100, digits = 3)```. So it is also like a placeholder for arguments?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add some explanation or code instead of using comments as you did.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to test this out yourself by writing a simple function:

```r
f <- function(...) return(list(...))

f("hello", a = 1, b = 2:6)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "hello"
#> 
#> $a
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 2 3 4 5 6
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>